# Change Nameservers on a domain that I don't control

Tags: domain-registrar, nameserver

I'm working for a client that's in a bit of a pickle.  Their domain is hosted through Nearly Free Speech by a webmaster who has fallen off the face of the earth.  The domain is pointed from Nearly Free Speech to Bluehost, which I have access to.  I'm trying to transfer the site from Bluehost to wpEngine, which means pointing the nameservers to Cloudflare.  It doesn't look like I can directly access the nameservers from Bluehost.  Is there a DNS record that does the same thing?

Alternatively, does anyone know how to deal with getting a domain back from an unresponsive webmaster?

Comment: Which domain registrar was used?   Do you have access to the domain registrar account?   Under whose name and email is the domain registered?

Comment: Other questions could be: Is the domain name the company name? Can the client provide an itemized receipt that includes domain name registration? Are any of the contact names, address, and phone the clients? You may need these to prove ownership. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name servers can only be changed from the domain registrar. You will need to logon to the registrar to make the changes. If the logon information isn't available because the MIA webmaster had them, you'll need to do a lost account recovery with the registrar.

Answer (score 1):

Whose name is on the Whois record for the domain?  Your clients name or the Webmaster?

In terms of the DNS issue, you can try logging into BlueHost and changing the A records so that they point to CloudFlare's IP addresses, though I'm not sure how successful this will be.   It will ultimately be better to actually change the Name Servers.